# Passing Value from Callback Method in Meteor with Mantra

Tags: javascript, meteor

**CONTEXT**

I'm using the Mantra architecture with Meteor 1.3 and [Astronomy](https://github.com/jagi/meteor-astronomy) to manage my collections. I'm trying to pass the id of the inserted object through the Meteor callback function to make use of it in my container.

**PROBLEM**
I get the right Id when i console log the element in the method, but get undefined when trying to console log it from a higher layer (from the file that holds my action which calls the Meteor method call). I'll then need to pass it from my actions to the Container that makes use of it.

**Method (on server)**

```
export default function () {
  Meteor.methods({
    'condition.create'(conditionTitle, conditionType, segmentId) {

      const condition = new Conditions();

      // Show the latency compensations
      Meteor._sleepForMs(500);

      // XXX: Do some user authorization
      // website._id = _id;
      condition.conditionTitle = conditionTitle;
      condition.segmentId = segmentId;
      condition.conditionType = conditionType;


      condition.save(function(err, id) {

        const conditionId = id;
        return conditionId;

      });


    }
  });

}
```

**Actions file (where the call is made - client side)**

```
export default {
  create({Meteor, LocalState, FlowRouter}, conditionTitle, conditionType, segmentId) {
    LocalState.set('CREATE_CONDITION_ERROR', null);

    if (!conditionTitle) {
      return LocalState.set('CREATE_CONDITION_ERROR', 'Condition Title is required!');
    }

    if (!conditionType) {
      return LocalState.set('CREATE_CONDITION_ERROR', 'Condition Type is required!');
    }


    if (!segmentId) {
    return LocalState.set('CREATE_CONDITION_ERROR', 'segmentId is required.');
    }

    LocalState.set('CREATE_CONDITION_ERROR', null);




    Meteor.call('condition.create', conditionTitle, conditionType, segmentId, function(err, conditionId) {

        if (err) {
          return LocalState.set('CREATE_CONDITION_ERROR', err.message);
        } else {
          console.log("method" + conditionId);
        }
    });

  },

  clearErrors({LocalState}) {
    return LocalState.set('CREATE_CONDITION_ERROR', null);
  }
};
```

**Container (partial snippet on client - this is where I need to make use of the conditionId)**

```
onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault;
    const {create, segmentId} = this.props;
    const conditionTitle = this.state.conditionTitle;
    const conditionType = this.state.conditionType;

    create(conditionTitle, conditionType, segmentId, function(conditionId) {

      console.log(conditionId);

    });


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue did not have anything to do with Mantra. I was returning the  inserted object inside the Astronomy .save function, but was not passing that value to the entire Meteor method. Hence the undefined.

This was the correct method on the server:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'condition.create'(conditionTitle, conditionType, segmentId) {

      const conditionAstro = new Conditions();

      // Show the latency compensations
      Meteor._sleepForMs(500);

      // XXX: Do some user authorization
      // website._id = _id;
      conditionAstro.conditionTitle = conditionTitle;
      conditionAstro.segmentId = segmentId;
      conditionAstro.conditionType = conditionType;


      const condition = conditionAstro.save(function(err, id) {

        // const conditionId = id;
        console.log(id);
        return id;

      });

      return condition;


    }
  });
```